# Questions on Google Email Mark Up recurring Emails from Production Server

Tags: markup, google-schemas

According to Google Mark Up document, we need to send email to minimum 100 gmail addresses every day during 3-4 weeks using 1 domain before we send email mark up example to Gmail account created for test purpose. we have below questions,

1. Is it really necessary to have 100 emails per subdomain? Or per IP is it enough?
2. When we launch every single subdomain (meaning country), do we need to re-do this step?
3. Once it’s approved and we will run Email Mark up functionality, should we send Email Mark up embedded emails to 100 gmail everyday?  Or should we send whatever the content (like dummy) to 100 gmails? Or it’s required only before submission of Email Mark up request so it will not be relevant anymore?

Please clarify these so that we can proceed for next steps.

Comment: Hi All, Can we please get a response on the above questions.